# Перевод прописи в число

Tags: алгоритм

Появилась небольшая задачка нужно перевести строку содержащую прописные числа в более понятный компьютеру вариант. Пример: пятьдесят восемь -> 58. Нужна готовая реализация.

Comment: Готовая, говорите?

Comment: Влад, все мы любим готовое ;-)

Comment: Интересно, не нужна ли ещё поддержка узбекского и латыни? И сленга (ну там, "стопицот" -> 100500, "лимон" -> 1000000).

Comment: Вопрос интересный, только сначала надо определиться с распознаванием кодировки и языка.

А в остальном согласен с @Deonis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Нужна готовая реализация.

Сомневаюсь, даже практически уверен, что таковой нет. Объясню. Представьте, если бы нам надо было произвести обратные действия (*58 -> пятьдесят восемь*), то для начала, мы бы нашли число в контексте (что не трудно), разбили бы его на разряды и каждым из них, пробежались бы по подготовленным заранее и соответствующим массивам, где из десяток нашли бы ключь "5" со значением "пятьдесят", из единиц - "8" со значением "восемь", поменяли и были бы в шоколаде.

А вот теперь вернемся к вашему примеру... Мы запнемся уже на стадии нахождения прописного числа в тексте. И не среди цифр, а среди таких же слов, как и "пятьдесят восемь".

Comment: А я оптимист, уверен, что кто-то реализовал такой алгоритм. Правда, пока его найти не удалось. Нахождение прописного числа в тексте сложная задача? Я вас умоляю.

Comment: @psyhitus: если всё так просто, почему бы вам самому не сделать и выложить для нас готовую реализацию?

Comment: @psyhitus, вы разве у меня в ответе где-то прочитали, что это не возможно? Наоборот! Я думаю, что в какой-то мере, алгоритм поиска того же гугля, уже, если не на сто процентов, но реализовал данную фишку. Только вот я "земной человек". ))

Comment: @VladD, думаю так и получится.

Comment: @Deonis вы слишком мрачно обрисовали картину. Есть словарь чисел в промежутке 0 - 9 и 11 - 19 (19 ключей). Отдельно числа дробные десяти: 10, 20 и т.д. (9 ключей). Отдельно сотни (9 ключей). Ключи для значений тысяч[а,и], миллион[а,ов]. И несколько правил, определяющих последовательности. Если дальше миллиона не ходить - то получаем 43 ключа. Можно сократить кол-во ключей в десятках и сотнях.

Comment: @Deonis Что касается поиска, то искать можно ключи в тексте, а можно каждое слово текста проверять на соответствие ключу. Второй вариант предпочтительнее, если нужно пройтись по тексту и заменить прописной вариант, на численный. Далее уже дело техники.

Все станет сильно хуже, если нужно учитывать опечатки и орфографические ошибки. Хотя можно применить статистический метод.

Comment: @a_gura, наверное Вы правы. Только словарь получится побольше, поскольку надо учесть разные словоформы (т.е. *три, трех, трем* и т.п.).

Но и тут не все так тривиально. Иногда понадобится распознавать смысл текста. А то, древнескандинавский бог Один превратится в цифорку 1!

Кстати, к **трем** это тоже относится.

Comment: @a_gura, подводные камни появляются, когда начинаешь делать. Пример может из "пальца высосаный", но все же, если числа будут на пересечении предложений: "**Было пятьсот, тридцать три отдали**". Дело ясное, что надо учитывать знаки препинания, но если не учесть, то число выдаст **533**.

Если есть желание, то кто ж против? Пусть ТС делает. Получиться? Так я только рад за него буду.

Comment: @avp Да, словоформы цифр не учел. Спасиюо за замечание.

Про Одина круто. Но "двадцать Один" определенно не про богов :) 

Вообще я не понял, откуда взялось столько сложностей, т.к. вопрос изначально был про перевод одной формы в другую. А свели все это чуть ли не к написанию Яндекса.

Comment: @Deonis главное, чтобы потом поделился результатом с сообществом ;)

Comment: Google умеет такое делать, правда, ввод текста голосовой)

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть вариант, только он по функции на оборот делает, думаю там не сильно сложно переделать под вашу задачу [Кликни меня](http://php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14005)

А вообще я бы реализовать через элементарную функцию str_replace() =)